# Docker port exposed to outside world

Tags: docker, networking, network-programming, dockerfile

I've installed docker in a VM which is publicy available on internet. I've installed mongodb in a docker container in the VM.Mongodb is listening on `27017` port.
I've installed using the following steps

```
 docker run -p 27017:27017 --name da-mongo -v ~/mongo-data:/data/db -d mongo
```

The port from container is redirected to the host using the `-p` flag. But the port `27017` is exposed on the internet. I don't want it to happen.

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want it available for certain hosts then you need a firewall. But, if all you need is it working on localhost (your VM machine), then you don't need to expose/bind the port with the host. I suggest you to run the container without the -p option, then, run the following command:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' your_container_id_or_name
```

After that, it will display an IP, it is the IP of the container you've just ran (Yes, docker uses somewhat an internal virtual network connecting your containers and your host machine between them).

After that, you can connect to it using the IP and port combination, something like:

```
172.17.0.2:27017
```

Comment: If I hardcode the IP to the application logic, if the container is stopped and again started will the IP remain same?

Comment: Yes, when the container is ran, the IP will remain the same as long as you don't delete it. Or well, you can also edit your hosts file and add a name to your containers IP, then you will only have to use it's given name instead of it's IP, and if the later changes, then you will just have to modify your hosts file

Answer (score 1):

When you publish the port, you can select which host interface to publish on:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:27017:27017 --name da-mongo \
  -v ~/mongo-data:/data/db -d mongo
```

That will publish the container port 27017 to host interface 127.0.0.1 port 27017. You can only add the interface to the host port, the container itself must still bind to 0.0.0.0.